# Do Xbox Live subscriptions stack duration?

Tags: xbox-network

I have one month of Xbox live. If I register my 1 year subscription, will it stack? Never tried, just wondering, don't want to waste my money.

Answer (score 6):

When you purchase a new Xbox Live subscription and add it to your account its start date will be the nearest date in the future which you will not currently be subscribed to Xbox Live.

So go ahead and add more time, it won't overlap your current time so you won't waste money.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, buying more Xbox live does 'stack' as you thought.

When you have 3 months left of Xbox live and you buy a year more, you now have 1 year and 3 months left.

It is also always consecutive and immediate, you have from now until your subscription runs out and there is no way to 'hold' or 'pause' your subscription for any time that you are not using it.

Answer (score 2):

TL:DR Yes

Yes, they do stack. If you have 3 months on your account and you buy another 30 days you have 4 months on your account now.
Look at Xbox Live membership in days. If I have 24 days of my 30 gold days left and I buy on another 60 days I have 84 days now. Hope that helps